# Grep a "text" and print all the line before and after the text. each log session is separated by 2 blank lines

Tags: linux, awk, grep

```
1  
1  
1  
1  
  Text  
11
1  
1  
1
```

The text above can be anywhere therefore grep -C wont help.
I have tried that using AWK but i want to do it using grep

```
zgrep -C25 "Text" engine.*.log.gz
```

doesn't work as text may appear anywhere

I know the `awk` option but it doesn't work on .gz file i have to convert it its a lengthy  process
  `awk -v RS= '/Text/' engine.*.log.gz`

Comment: Welcome to SO, special thanks for showing your efforts in form of code in your question, keep it up.Could you please EDIT your sample of input and add sample of expected output in your question and let us know then as it is not that clear as of now.

Comment: Maybe something like `zgrep -Poz "[^\n]*\n[^\n]*Text[^\n]*\n[^\n]*" engine.*.log.gz`? No overlapping matches though.

Comment: if you system doesn't have `zgrep`, you can still uncompress it on the fly, send the output to stdout, and read in a pipe with `grep`, ie. `gunzip -c file.gz | grep -C25 target`. You'll have to write your own program to actually read inside a compressed file to find what you want, and in any case, you'd need to uncompress the file anyway. .....

Comment: Post your best attempt at solving your problem with`awk`, as only logic can solve your problem, and `grep` can't do any complex logic. Good luck.

Comment: Although `cat path | awk ...` is rightly avoided as UUOC, `zcat path | awk ...` is a perfectly good pattern.

Comment: this is what i usually do

Answer (score 3):

Just do it the trivial, obvious, robust, portable way:

```
zcat engine.*.log.gz | awk -v RS= '/Text/{print; exit}'
```

That should also be pretty efficient since the `SIGPIPE` that `zcat` gets when `awk` exits on finding the first `Text` should terminate the `zcat`.

Or if `Text` can appear multiple times in the input and you want all associated records output:

```
zcat engine.*.log.gz | awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/Text/'
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you so much for the help, but I figured out the solution

`zgrep -C34 "text" engine.*.log.gz |awk  '/20yy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss/,/SENT MESSAGES (asynchronous)/'`

1. Search the "text" along side 34 lines before and after it to get average out all the lines required
2. All of my logs session always begins with date and time so is used AWK for that
3. All of my logs session always ends with "SENT MESSAGES (asynchronous):" So AWK did that trick for me.

Comment: What's the benefit of doing that over a simple `zcat engine.*.log.gz | awk -v RS= '/Text/{print; exit}'` (or some equally trivial `zcat | awk`) though? Be aware that what you have could produce output for blocks that do not contain `text`, e.g. if such a "bad" block started within 34 lines of `text` within a "good" block then the `zgrep` would include [part of] that "bad" block in it's output and then the `awk` would treat it as a separate "good" block, so it's not robust. Your range end regexp doesn't do what you think btw since `(` is an RE metacharacter.